# commit not found when syncing submodule

Tags: git, linux-kernel, git-submodules

I have an old code that has sub-modules. When I ran this command to update the submodules, I am getting the error that one of the submodules are not able to find the requested commit:

```
$ git submodule update --init --recursive
fatal: remote error: upload-pack: not our ref 1e07d0ce57c1bd5cf2e9b279deca2e959de88135
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
Fetched in submodule path 'linux', but it did not contain 1e07d0ce57c1bd5cf2e9b279deca2e959de88135. Direct fetching of that commit failed.
```

How can I find which submodule is this error coming from and how can I change the commit to something that can work (possibly some newer version of that commit which I believe was removed from the sub-module repository.

I believe this is related to the Linux kernel, as it is pointing to Linux but I am not sure. From what I could find the code was using Linux Kernal5.12.19 which is not supported and hence maybe it is already removed form the Linux kernel repository.

Comment: See the `Fetched in submodule path 'linux'` part for which submodule.

Comment: @torek There is nothing under the linux directory.

Comment: That's because the fetch failed. Without the correct commit to check out, Git did not check out any commit.

Comment: @torek How can I fix it? I can go to linux repository and find an LTS version of the kernel and its commit, but how to update my repository to use that commit instead of the one that it is set up now?

Comment: The reference *to* the commit—the hash ID needed *from the submodule* —is stored in a commit *in the superproject*. You can't fix a missing commit, you can only find a suitable *different* commit and use that from the superproject. How do you find a "suitable commit"? That's the pay-$-to-a-consultant question.

Comment: @torek I can find a suitable commit ID, but how to update my repository to use the new hash instead of the old one?

Comment: Enter the submodule and check out the commit you want. Return to the superproject and add that commit hash ID as the gitlink. (Search for *gitlink*.)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a practical example. I've created a couple of example repositories to reproduce this problem, so that I have:

```
$ git clone upstream1 repo1
$ cd repo1
$ git submodule
-3c913516ad30ca52603cb319d68169939156523e example-submodule
```

If I try to update the submodule, it fails with a missing commit:

```
$ git submodule update --init
Submodule 'example-submodule' (/home/lars/tmp/repo/upstream2) registered for path 'example-submodule'
Cloning into '/home/lars/tmp/repo/tmp1/example-submodule'...
done.
fatal: git upload-pack: not our ref 3c913516ad30ca52603cb319d68169939156523e
fatal: remote error: upload-pack: not our ref 3c913516ad30ca52603cb319d68169939156523e
fatal: Fetched in submodule path 'example-submodule', but it did not contain 3c913516ad30ca52603cb319d68169939156523e. Direct fetching of that commit failed.
```

I happen to know that commit `d91db5c146cd531b6b7c1a0e4445b98eb5ae02c5` is a valid commit and an appropriate replacement for `3c913516ad30ca52603cb319d68169939156523e`, so to repair things I can check out that commit in the submodule:

```
$ cd example-submodule
$ git checkout d91db5c146cd531b6b7c1a0e4445b98eb5ae02c5
$ cd ..
$ git commit -m 'Updated submodule' example-submodule
```